# What is Google App Engine concurrent connection limit / how is it scalable?

Tags: google-app-engine

What is Google App Engine concurrent connection limit?

Let assume that the most request finishes in 5s.

Comment: how much $ do you have? That's the limit :P

Comment: If something earn money there is no limits? :)

Comment: Well, in essence. New instances can be created to serve increased traffic automatically. This scaling is in essence what GAE does for you "for free".

Answer (score 2):

There is not a connection limit, but rather a frontend execution time limit (28 hr/day, USD 0.08/h above that), and an incoming bandwidth (1GB free/day, unlimited free with billing enabled), and outgoing bandwidth (1GB free/day, USD 0.12/GB). I suggest you read Google's billing information and stop asking these questions here: https://cloud.google.com/pricing/.

Comment: I know pricing very well it is not what I asked - do you run large application on GAE?

Comment: @Chameleon: Supposedly, according to Google, infinitely. But I suggest you wait till it happens.

Comment: Good comment but still not know the limit - tell me if you reach first :)

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of a maximum of 10 simultaneous threads allowed by instances.  If you need more simultaneous requests, new instances will be started.  BTW a 5s request seems pretty long when running on GAE.

If you are using GAE Java you might be hit by this really annoying issue:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7865